# Determinant of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this matrix considered real with non real eigenvalues? $\begin{bmatrix} \cos x&-5\\ 5&\cos x\\  \end{bmatrix}$ When I made this matrix up, at the moment it looked like a real matrix with non real eigenvalues, specifically, the complex eigenvalues. But now, I am not that sure.

**Edited:** the OP changed the matrix.

Comment: How did you compute its eigenvalues?

Comment: $(cosx-\lambda)^2$+25=0 => (cosx-\lambda)=5i

Answer (score 4):

**After edit by the OP:** Yes. Assuming your $x$ is real, the matrix that you (now) give us has complex eigenvalues. The below discussion was from when you gave us a matrix which actually had real eigenvalues; it points the way to finding real matrices with complex eigenvalues.  It still describes a way to find simpler examples.

---

If you want to find a $2\times 2$ matrix which has real coefficients but complex eigenvalues, consider the following: for the matrix
$$
A:=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix},
$$
we have
$$
\det(A-\lambda I)=(a-\lambda)(d-\lambda)-bc=\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+(ad-bc)=0
$$
precisely when
$$
\lambda=\frac{(a+d)\pm\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)}}{2}.
$$
In order for this to have no real roots (and hence two complex roots), it is then necessary and sufficient to choose $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such that
$$
(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)<0.
$$
So, for instance, you could choose $a=d=0$ and $b=1$, $c=-1$. You get the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
which you can check has eigenvalues $\pm\ i$.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate. We get the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-2\lambda\cos x+\cos ^2 x-25=0$. The discriminant of the quadratic is positive, so the eigenvalues are real.

But there is an easy fix: change **one** of the $5$'s to $-5$.

Answer (score 1):

Every symmetric real matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$ and their eigenvalues are roots of the characteristic polynomial so in your case
$$\chi_A(t)=\det(A-tI)=(t-(\cos x-5))(t-(\cos x+5))$$

**Added** $\ $ The OP changed the matrix to an antisymmetric real matrix so it's diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are pure complex numbers and the same calculus with the characteristic polynomial gives the eigenvalues:
$$\cos x+5i\quad;\quad \cos x-5i$$